# How do I redirect my .eth domain with eth.link?

Tags: ipfs, swarm, ens

Let's say I want to redirect `somewebsite.eth.link` to `www.otherdomainiown.com`.  http://spacex.eth.link/ does this and the redirect works on chrome.  However, I don't see an A record and I do see IPFS content in the records: https://app.ens.domains/name/spacex.eth

I read [http://eth.link/](http://eth.link) but did not understand it all.

It seems that if I set a DNS A record to `somewebsite.eth.link` then the redirect will automatically happen?

What should that DNS A record look like in this scenario?

What field and attribute in the resolver do I fill with that record (text record, something else)?

I'd like to make this work without IPFS / Swarm.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to make this work without IPFS / Swarm

From my research and experimentation, this isn't possible without IPFS. If you look at DNS A record for `spacex.eth.link` you will see that it points to a Cloudflare IP, as Cloudflare provides the eth.link gateway to IPFS.

`% drill spacex.eth.link`

```
<snip>

;; ANSWER SECTION:
spacex.eth.link.    106 IN  A   104.17.64.14
spacex.eth.link.    106 IN  A   104.17.96.13

<snip>
```

Good further reading starts here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-distributed-web-resolver/